# Variable in initializer SwiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui, swiftui-navigationlink

I have this code:

```
import SwiftUI
import QGrid

struct VerCanales: View {
    
    var categoria:String
    @ObservedObject var canales = CargarCanales(categoriaID: categoria)
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView{
            QGrid(self.canales.listaCanales, columns: 3){item in
                NavigationLink(destination:VlcPlayerDemo()){
                    Text(item.name).frame(width:400, height:50)
                }
            }
            
        }.navigationBarTitle(Text("CHANNELS AVAILABLE"))
    }
}
```

The varibale "categoria" comes from the previous view as a parameter and I need to pass it as a parameter to the @ObservedObject but I have the following error: "Cannot use instance member 'categoria' within property initializer; property initializers run before 'self' is available"

I am new in the Swift language and I have searched but cannot find a good solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to initialize canales variable inside the VerCanales view init.

```
struct VerCanales: View {
    
    private var categoria: String
    @ObservedObject var canales: CargarCanales
    
    init(categoria: String, canales: CargarCanales) {
        self.categoria = categoria
        self.canales = canales
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView{
            QGrid(self.canales.listaCanales, columns: 3){item in
                NavigationLink(destination:VlcPlayerDemo()){
                    Text(item.name).frame(width:400, height:50)
                }
            }
            
        }.navigationBarTitle(Text("CHANNELS AVAILABLE"))
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, but now, in the previous View which variable should I send ? `NavigationLink(destination:VerCanales(categoria: item.categoryID, canales: HERE )){ Text(item.categoryName).frame(width:400, height:50) `

Comment: For this make var canales to private and remove canales from init parameter.  
```
 @ObservedObject private var canales: CargarCanales
    
    init(categoria: String) {
        self.categoria = categoria
        self.canales = CargarCanales(categoriaID: categoria)
    }
```